# Appending buttons to a modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been trying to copy this [demo](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) (under "Live demo"). I have the following code which works:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .on("click", function (d) {

        $(".modal-body").empty();
        $(".modal-header").empty();

        $(".modal-header").append("<h4>" + d.name + "</h4>");
        $(".modal-body").append("<p>URL: " + d.relativePath + "</p>");

        for (var key in d.verbDocDict) {
            if (d.verbDocDict.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                console.log(key + ": " + d.verbDocDict[key])
                 -----> $(".modal-body").append("<p><a>" + key + ": " + d.verbDocDict[key].document + "</a></p>");
                console.log("<p>This <a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default popover-test\" title=\"A Title\" data-content=\"And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?\">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>")
                //$(".modal-mody").append("<p>This <a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default popover-test\" title=\"A Title\" data-content=\"And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?\">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>")
            }
        }
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    })
```

Modal displayed:

[image: Image displaying modal]

I'm trying to change the verbs to buttons that can be clicked like in the demo using this code:

```
$(".modal-mody").append("<p>This <a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default popover-test\" title=\"A Title\" data-content=\"And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?\">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>")
```

However, this does not work and the modal body is blank.

Does anybody know how to correctly display buttons in this manner?

**Edit**

Here is my modal:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly me - it was a typo:

```
$(".modal-mody").append("<p>This <a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default popover-test\" title=\"A Title\" data-content=\"And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?\">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>")
```

Instead of

```
$(".modal-body").append("<p>This <a href=\"#\" role=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default popover-test\" title=\"A Title\" data-content=\"And here's some amazing content. It's very engaging. right?\">button</a> should trigger a popover on click.</p>")
```

doh